# New line characters in apache error log

Tags: apache-httpd

I was checking through my `access.log` file and I came across the following lines:

```
66.240.236.119 - - [26/Apr/2019:04:15:56 +0200] "\n" 400 3245 "-" "-"
66.240.236.119 - - [26/Apr/2019:04:15:58 +0200] "\n" 400 3261 "-" "-"
66.240.236.119 - - [26/Apr/2019:04:15:58 +0200] "\n" 400 3239 "-" "-"
66.240.236.119 - - [26/Apr/2019:04:15:59 +0200] "\n" 400 3239 "-" "-"
66.240.236.119 - - [26/Apr/2019:04:16:00 +0200] "\n" 400 3239 "-" "-"
```

How come the method is `\n`? I've not come across this before in access logs so I'm a little concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like somebody triggered a "newline request" like

```
 printf '\n' | nc localhost 80
```

which produces this in the access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2019:01:39:38 +0200] "\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Probably to test your server...

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Seems to be a Shodan IP, but it was just weird as I've had emails about my box being attacked, so just wanted to be sure. Very interesting. What could someone get out of this?

Comment: I guess it's some kind of vulnerability test with weird request content, but I can't tell...

Comment: Oh, okay. No worries, thank you!